# indexOf array in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I am most likely overlooking something something pretty basic here, but I have a really hard time figuring out why I get the following behaviour, when looking for a specific array in another array:

```
myArray.push(["Name", 1, 2]);
myArray.indexOf(["Name", 1, 2]);
```

Returns -1.. Why can't I find the array that I just pushed?

Comment: Because each time you use `[`…`]` you create a _new_ array. `indexOf` compares references.

Comment: That makes sense. Can you give me heads up on how to achieve the behaviour im looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript search array of arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315180/javascript-search-array-of-arrays)

Comment: This seems to be a duplicated question.
Here is the link to a quit similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943200/javascript-2d-array-indexof

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var myArray = [];
var anotherArray = ["Name", 1, 2];

myArray.push(anotherArray);
myArray.indexOf(anotherArray);  // returns 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var checkArray = ["Name", 1, 2]
var myArray = [];

myArray.push(checkArray);
myArray.indexOf(checkArray);
```