# check if subarray is in other array ExtJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs

i want to check if an array containes other array in ExtJs
i tried this but without success

```
if( [2,1] in [1,2,3]){
     console.log("true"); }
```

i know that i can do it manualy but is there a direct methode

Comment: Are both arrays guaranteed to be unique? Does order matter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript 2d array indexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943200/javascript-2d-array-indexof)

Comment: no order doesn't matter Evan

Comment: i saw it it's not the same Taki

Comment: @Amor.o you should use Ext.Array utility object, have a look to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr1=[2,1],
    arr2=[1,2,3];

if(Ext.Array.merge(arr1,arr2).length===arr2.length){
    console.log('HELLO!');
}
```

If you're using Extjs, using this method you can win without functions and cicles

Simply merging the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the Array to check if the values are in it:

```js
function inArray(v, a){
  for(var i=0,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
    if(a[i] === v){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
function allInArray(t, a){
  for(var i=0,l=t.length; i<l; i++){
    if(!inArray(t[i], a)){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
var yourArray = [1, 2, 3], tests = [2, 1];
console.log(allInArray(tests, yourArray));
console.log(allInArray([2, 4, 1], yourArray));

// another way
function allIn(t, a){
  return t.length === t.map(x => +a.includes(x)).reduce((n, v) => n+v);
}
console.log(allIn(tests, yourArray));
console.log(allIn([3, 4], yourArray));
```

Comment: thank u i already have a solution like that but i ask if there is a direct solution , that's means with a predefined function

Answer (score 0):

In extjs you have Ext.each function to loop out through the array

```
var array_1 = [2,1];
var array_2 = [1,2,3];
Ext.each(array_1,function(value_of_arr1){
    if(array_2.indexOf(value_of_arr1) == -1){
        console.log('array_1 value doesnt exist');
        return;
    }else{
        console.log('array_1 value does exist');
        return;
    }
});
```

In above code the -1 is returned from the if condition 
if the value of 
array_1 is not found in the array_2

if value is found the array index in which the value resides is returned