# Remove array from inside array based on index in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-splice

I have an array which looks like:-

```
[[0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [1,1], [1,2]...]
```

I am looking to remove one of the arrays from this array based on the `indexOf()` but I keep getting a value of `-1`, which removes the last item from the array when I try the following code:-

```js
array = [[0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [1,1], [1,2]];
console.log('Removed value', array.splice(array.indexOf([0,3]), 1));
console.log('Result', array);
```

would somebody be able to point me in the right direction to help solve this issue I am having?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This other post should point you in the right direction. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943200/javascript-2d-array-indexof

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `indexOf` because when you declare `[0,3]` in `array.splice(array.indexOf([0,3]), 1))` you're creating a new array and this new object is not inside your `array` (but rather another array that has the same values).

You can use `findIndex` instead as follows (example):

```
array.findIndex(x => x[0] === 0 && x[1] === 3)
```

this will return `2` - now you can use it to delete:

```
array.splice(2, 1)
```

Comment: Consider nixing `delete` in favor of `splice`. `delete` replaces the item at index 2 with `undefined`. I don't think that is what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If it is OK to remove every occurrence of `[0,3]`, then consider [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) combined with array destructuring of the lambda arguments. It offers a slightly leaner syntax than the other solutions.

```js
const input = [
    [0,1],
    [0,2],
    [0,3],
    [1,1],
    [1,2]
];


const result = input.filter(([x,y]) => !(x==0 && y==3));
console.log('Result=', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

To explain why your solution will not work:

Comparison operators only work for values not passed by a reference. When dealing references, comparison operators always return false, *unless* the two references point to the same object. (See this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Comparing_Objects))

An example:

```
a = [0,1]
b = a
b === a //true. a and b point to the same array.
a === [0,1] //false. a points to a different array than [0,1]
b[0] = 2
a[0] //2 - b points to the same array as a
```

To give you a solution (borrows from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4025958/10965456))

```
//Function to compare the values inside the arrays, and determine if they are equal. 
//Note: does not recurse.
function arraysEqual(arr1, arr2) {
    if(arr1.length !== arr2.length)
        return false;
    for(var i = arr1.length; i--;) {
        if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

array = [[0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [1,1], [1,2]];
//Find the index where x has the same values as [0,3]
array.findIndex(x => arraysEqual(x, [0,3])) //2
```