# Find Array[1D] in Array[2D] and return index

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array, google-sheets

have any way can find a match index in array[2D] faster?
I know compare 1 by 1 can make this ok, but i don't wanted to.

I tried this one, but it only can return -1

```
// mainsheetvalues is array[1D],
[1,2,3,4,5]


// AsheetValues is array [2D]
[
  [1,2,3,4,5],
  [6,7,8,9,0]
]

Logger.log(mainsheetvalues.indexOf(AsheetValues))
```

Comment: 1.What is the expected output? 2.Do you want to search  number 1 or array [1,2,3,4,5]?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript 2d array indexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943200/javascript-2d-array-indexof)

Comment: thankful for all helping , many thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943200/javascript-2d-array-indexof), we cannot compare two arrays directly. You need to generate some custom logic for the comparison. I have added a logic below. Hope this helps.

```js
const AsheetValues  = [
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    [6,7,8,9,0]
]   
const mainsheetvalues  = [1,2,3,4,5];
const isIncluded = (parentArr, childArr) => {
    let isMatch = true;
    for(let parentLoopIndex = 0; parentLoopIndex < parentArr.length; parentLoopIndex++) {
        if (parentArr[parentLoopIndex].length != childArr.length)
            isMatch = false;
        
            for (var i = 0; i < parentArr[parentLoopIndex].length; i++) {
                if (parentArr[parentLoopIndex][i] != childArr[i]) { 
                    isMatch = false;   
                }           
            }   
            if (isMatch)  {
                parentLoopIndex = parentArr.length;
            }    
        }
    return isMatch;
}

console.log(isIncluded(AsheetValues, mainsheetvalues));
```