# Javascripct 2d array IndexOf

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array like this

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]
```

How can I use array.IndexOf() to check which outer element in which an element occurs.
For example, if I enter 3, it should return 1(the position of the parent array).

Comment: array.IndexOf() doesn't work in your case , you have to write manual function then call it and get the index.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript 2d array indexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943200/javascript-2d-array-indexof)

Answer (score 1):

The `.indexOf()` method is good for when you want to find the index of a primitive value inside your array (or a value which you already have a reference to). Instead, you can use `.findIndex()`. Using `.findIndex()` will allow you to specify a function which you can return true from when an array matches your search criteria:

```js
const arr = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]

const search = 3;
const idx = arr.findIndex(inner => inner.includes(search));
console.log(idx);
```

Since you're asking to use `indexOf()` in your question, you could change the above function to use `indexOf()` instead of `.includes()` by checking if a valid index is returned:

```js
const arr = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]

const search = 3;
const idx = arr.findIndex(inner => inner.indexOf(search) >= 0);
console.log(idx);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.indexOf` works for flat arrays like `[1,2,3]`, but you can use `Array.findIndex` that accepts a function to filter.

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6],
  [7, 8],
  [9, 10]
]
const num = 3;
const index = arr.findIndex(([a, b]) => a === num || b === num);
console.log(index)
```